# Query for China Travelling

Tags: transit, india, china, new-delhi

In this Covid Situation, Chinese Nationals stranded in India.
What is the best route we can give them to travel to their own country?

Comment: What fo you mean by ‘best route’? Flight routing? Finding and booking a flight? Paperwork needed?

Comment: @Traveller International flights to and from India are currently extremely restricted.